# Django isn't displaying pages after a 404 error

Tags: django, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am hosting my site at entworks.in

The site seems to be working fine until I try to get a 404 error like entworks.in/asdf <-- will give 404. After that when I try to load other pages, like entworks.in, it shows 404 for all pages.

Anyone has any idea what might be the problem? I am running it on nginx.

EDIT:

## URLCONF

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from haystack.forms import ModelSearchForm
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
from haystack.views import search_view_factory

import bootlog.views

from bootlog.views import BSearchView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^about/', 'bootlog.views.profile_view', name='about'),
    url(r'^e/', 'bootlog.views.engineering_view', name='engineering'),
    url(r'^d/', 'bootlog.views.programming_view', name='programming'),
    url(r'^s/',search_view_factory(
        view_class=BSearchView,
        template='bootlog/base.html',
        searchqueryset = SearchQuerySet(),
        form_class=ModelSearchForm
        ), name='haystack_search'),
    url(r'^ckeditor/',include('ckeditor.urls')),
    url(r'^$',bootlog.views.front_page_view),
    url(r'^p/b(?P<blog_pk>\d+)p(?P<post_pk>\d+)/', bootlog.views.perma_post, name="blog-post"),
    url(r'^rss/$', bootlog.views.LatestEntriesFeed(), ),
    url(r'^all/',bootlog.views.html_render),
)

handler404='bootlog.views.view_404'
```

I am using gunicorn

EDIT 2:  I was displaying the 404 page in wrong way. Hence the error. It was overwriting the main config.

Comment: provide your django URLconf

Comment: are you using sWSGI / FastCGI / gunicorn?

Comment: Hi, I have added the data in main post